# PHP altering row output based on different column

Tags: php, row

I have some data outputting via PHP/MySQL. It's simply a list of Chinese characters that corresponds to a certain string.

```
$i = 0;

while ($i <= $x) {
    echo "<div class=\"char-option\"><a href=\"character.php?char=" . $results[$i]['id']. "\">" . $results[$i]['mainchar'] . "</a></div>";
    $i++;
}
```

I have another row with a character ranking in it, about 20% of the characters have a ranking. I would like to:

1. Change the class to "char-option char-common" for the character with the highest ranking.
2. Don't change the class if none of the characters have a ranking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine the 'ranking'?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Determine, WHICH character has the highest rank.

```
$high = -1, $hrank = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= $x; ++$i) {
    if(isset($results[$i]['rank']) && $hrank < $results[$i]['rank']) {
        $high = $i;
        $hrank = $results[$i]['rank'];
    }
}
```

Step 2: With the information, which has the highest character ranking, we can determine, who gets the normal class and who gets the additional class.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $x; ++$i) {
    $class = "char-option";   //Default class
    if($i == $high) $class .= " char-common"; //Adds the second class for the highest ranked character.
    echo "<div class=\"$class\"><a href=\"character.php?char=" . $results[$i]['id']. "\">" . $results[$i]['mainchar'] . "</a></div>";
}
```

The -1 in `$high` makes sure, that the class will not be changed, unless there is a ranking somewhere within the list.

Answer (score 0):

set your ranking in the result and do in this way.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= $x) {
  if ($results[$i]['highest_ranking'] == 1) {
    $class = "char-option char-common";
  } else {
    $class = "char-option";
  }
  echo "<div class=\"$class\"><a href=\"character.php?char=" . $results[$i]['id'] . "\">" . $results[$i]['mainchar'] . "</a></div>";
  $i++;
}
```